# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'long'

Tags: ios, pointers

I'm converting my iOS 6 app to work in iOS 7.  It uses CoreData and in my model I have a few entities and attributes defined.  One of the attributes is a deliveryid and the type is set to Integer 32.

I have NSManagedObject classes created for my core data entities and these worked fine previously in XCode 5 with iOS 6.

When I bring those NSManagedObject classes over to target iOS 7 I get the error "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'long'".

For the deliveryid attribute it is defined as follows in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * deliveryid;
```

then in the .m file I have:

```
NSString *strDeliveryID = [[NSNumber numberWithLong:self.deliveryid] stringValue];
```

where I try to convert to a string value.  This previously didn't create any warnings or issues when compiled.

I am unable to solve why the issue is appearing for iOS 7.  Can somebody help please?

Comment: This is not related either to Xcode nor to Core Data. You should learn the language better, then **read** the compiler error and **think about** what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.deliveryid` is already an `NSNumber*`. There is no reason to create a new `NSNumber*` out of it. Use this:

```
NSString *strDeliveryID = self.deliveryid.stringValue;
```

Another option is the following, which is silly and confusing:

```
NSString *strDeliveryID = @(self.deliveryid.longValue).stringValue;
```

Comment: Thank you.  So obvious now. :) I spent a while getting this to work in the iOS 6 version of the code as the compiler complained the opposite  when I used self.deliveryid.stringValue for iOS 6.

Comment: @motionpotion perhaps the variable was of type `long` instead of `NSNumber*` before? Query your version control system.

Comment: I didn't change the type of deliveryid between iOS 6 and iOS 7.  I set up a completely new project for iOS 7 and brought in the above code.  It didn't give a warning/issue in my iOS 6 project but does in iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
NSString *strDeliveryID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deliveryid];
```

Comment: are there any downsides to converting the deliveryid this way compared to the suggested answer by @rightfold ?

Comment: You can parse anything to string that way.Spend 10 min to check it our and you will see